# Any need to call unsubscribe for RxJS first()

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

In the following code:-

```
RxJS.Observable.of(1,2).first().subscribe((x) => console.log(x););
```

is it necessary to unsubscribe given the operator `first()`?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

No. It unsubscribes automatically after calling `first()`. The current syntax is  `observable.pipe(first()).subscribe(func);` for RxJS 6.

The [documentation](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/first#description) states:

> If called with no arguments, `first` emits the first value of the source Observable, then completes.

Comment: Think you are missing a `)` :)

Comment: what happens when the source observable never emits a value, does that mean that the Subscription stays there and possibly create a memory leak ?

Comment: @Gagan Yes, it can create a memory leak.

Comment: So how to add unsubscribing in this case?

Comment: takeUntil(this.destroyed$)

Where destroyed$ gets set on ngOnDestroy()

Answer (score 6):

For the example provided, you dont need to `unsubscribe`, and neither you need to call `first`, as `Observable.of(1)` actually *completes* after emitting its first (and last) value.

Comment: Changed to 1,2 but your answer still is correct since you mentioned it Completes.

Answer (score 3):

`first()` will complete after the first item is emitted from the observable.

Also `subscribe()` takes three arguments, the last one being the complete callback. Running the following code will output 1 followed by  'done'.

```
Rx.Observable.of(1)
  .subscribe(
  (x) => console.log(x),    // next
  (x) => console.error(x),  // error
  () => console.log('done') // done
)
```