# Do I need to unsubscribe to firestore snapshot listener if I use first()

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

If I am querying as in the example below with using first() to only return the first set of data and to ignore any updates.

Will I still be getting the updates to the client and being charged for the reads?

Should I use get() instead of snapshotChanges or onSnapshot or does using first() make it the same as get()?

```
getCompanies(searchText: string): Observable<Company[]> {
      return this.db.collection('companies', ref => ref
      .orderBy('name').startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + '\uf8ff')
    )
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(snaps => convertSnaps<Company>(snaps)),
        first()
      );
  }

export function convertSnaps<T>(snaps) {
  return <T[]>snaps.map(snap => {
    const data = convertDocTimeStampsToDate(snap.payload.doc.data());
    return {
      id: snap.payload.doc.id,
      ...data
    };
  });
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell it should auto-unsubscribe (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49683600/any-need-to-call-unsubscribe-for-rxjs-first) for a similar question about rxjs), but I can't find the relevant code in the [repo](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/tree/master/src/firestore).

Comment: If you know that you only need to query a single time, using `get()` is more explicit, and removes any doubt about unwanted reads.