# Can I add side-effects to scan

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have a problem: "When a mouse down, create a rectangle, resize it when move and complete when a mouse up".
I tried to use rxjs, but it is not really good solution:

```
import { scan, mergeMap, takeUntil, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';

const mouseDown$ = fromEvent(document, 'mousedown');
const mouseUp$ = fromEvent(document, 'mouseup');
const mouseMove$ = fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');

function createNode() {
  const node = document.createElement('DIV');
  node.setAttribute('style', 'position: absolute; border: 1px solid red;');
  document.body.appendChild(node);
  return node;
}

mouseDown$
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(() => {
      return mouseMove$.pipe(
        takeUntil(mouseUp$),
        scan((node, e: MouseEvent) => {
          if (!node) {
            let x = null;
            x = createNode();
            x.style.top = `${e.clientY}px`;
            x.style.left = `${e.clientX}px`;
            return x;
          } else {
            node.style.bottom = `${e.clientY}px`;
            node.style.right = `${e.clientX}px`;
          }
          return node;
        }, null)
      );
    })
  )
  .subscribe(() => {});
```

The problem is the side-effects is added to the method "scan"
Do you have much better solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid a inner pipe side-effect (what is in general a good thing) you can split your logic into two different `Observables/Subscriptions`:

**Create Node Observable**

```js
let node = null

const createNode$ = mouseDown$.pipe(
  switchMapTo(mouseMove$.pipe(
    takeUntil(mouseUp$),
    take(1)
  ))
)

createNode$.subscribe(createNode)

function createNode(e: MouseEvent) {
  const node = document.createElement('DIV');
  node.setAttribute('style', 'position: absolute; border: 1px solid red;');
  document.body.appendChild(node);
  x.style.top = `${e.clientY}px`;
  x.style.left = `${e.clientX}px`;
  return node;
}
```

**Update Node Obsservable**

```js
const updateNode$ = mouseDown$.pipe(
  switchMapTo(mouseMove$.pipe(
    takeUntil(mouseUp$),
    skip(1)
  ))
)

updateNode$.subscribe(updateNode(node))

function updateNode(node: Node) {
  return function(e: MouseEvent) {
    node.style.bottom = `${e.clientY}px`;
    node.style.right = `${e.clientX}px`;
  }
}
```

I do not prefer the above one to your solution - they are both equal imo. It's just a way to possibly avoid side-effects. There are several opinions onto when and why to avoid side-effects. I personally try to reduce them as much as I can but there are some scenarios where it's just not worth going for it (or I might just have not seen a good solution).

I once asked a question about [when-should-i-create-a-new-subscription-for-a-specific-side-effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60258257/when-should-i-create-a-new-subscription-for-a-specific-side-effect). The answer can give you some details about when and why it can be useful to avoid side-effects.